# Why does pandas convert dtype when doing row by row build of data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

The following behavior in pandas just caused me some debug time so I thought I would share it. I think it might be a bug but not sure. In the first case the dataframe contains the correct dtype for uint64, in the second case when building row by row it seems to auto convert to float64. Also, I know there are better ways to create dataframes than row by row for most cases but still seems that it should not behave this way. My question is whether this is a bug or expected behavior. This might be related to [returning coerced dtype](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11617) which is all I could find searching.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
tmp_float = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0]).astype('float64')
tmp_int = np.array([1,2,3]).astype('uint64')
nonrow_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'float': tmp_float, 'uint': tmp_int})
print(nonrow_dataframe['uint'].dtype)
row_dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
row = 0
for i in range(3):
    row_dataframe.at[row, 'float'] = tmp_float[i]
    row_dataframe.at[row, 'uint'] = tmp_int[i]
    row +=1
print(row_dataframe['uint'].dtype)
```

Comment: Seems more related to [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15231).

Comment: My best guess is that using `.loc/.at` might extend the `DataFrame` first, which creates a `NaN` and forces a conversion to float. On the other hand, you can first define the column dtype (before the loop) with the new `'Int64'`, which is capable of holding `NaN` and no coercion to float will occur.

Comment: @ALollz Can you show me how to first define the dtype and make it work when adding an extra row? I tried several ways and anytime I  added an extra row it converts again. Also a reference to the new dtype you mention would be helpful, I could only find `int64`.

Comment: @ZakKeirn which version of `pandas` do you have? `'Int64'` is only available as of 0.24

Answer (score 0):

My *best* guess is that when using `.at` or `.loc` to assign, it might be extending first, which creates the `NaN` placeholder, forcing coercion of the `int` column to `float`. Definitely in your above case where you first assign the float column, this requires a `NaN` placeholder to be placed in the `unit` column on the same row (for the second and subsequent rows) before filling with the `tmp_int` value, so this coerces the column to `float`. `pandas` wont automatically downcast the column back.

On the other hand, if you first define the dtype, using the new `'Int64'` type capable of holding `NaN` the coercion does not occur:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
tmp_float = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0]).astype('float64')
tmp_int = np.array([1,2,3]).astype('uint64')

row_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['float', 'int'])
row_df = row_df.astype({'float': 'float64', 'int': 'Int64'})
for i in range(3):
    row_df.at[i, 'float'] = tmp_float[i]
    row_df.loc[i, 'int'] = tmp_int[i]

print(row_df)
#   float  int
#0    1.0    1
#1    2.0    2
#2    3.0    3

row_df.dtypes
#float    float64
#int        Int64
#dtype: object

type(row_df.loc[0, 'int'])
#numpy.int64
```

Comment: Can I safely cast back to `uint64` ?  I need to compare to previous data using `uint64`. Here is link to docs on this for those interested: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html